# How can you calculate scale and shape parameters for lognormal distribution in R?

Tags: r, distribution, survival-analysis

I have fitted lognormal distribution to some dataset in R using `library (survival)` and `survreg()`. The output below is showing me both intercept and log (scale). However, I need to calculate the scale parameter (σ) and shape parameter (m) for this distribution. Is there a formula to calculate this using the values I got for intercept and log (scale) or is there any other way to do this?

```
>summary(model)

Call:
survreg(formula = Surv(times_start, times_end, type = "interval2") ~ 
    1, dist = "lognormal")
            Value Std. Error     z       p
(Intercept) 3.207      0.191 16.78 < 2e-16
Log(scale)  0.442      0.116  3.81 0.00014

Scale= 1.56 

Log Normal distribution
Loglik(model)= -224.3   Loglik(intercept only)= -224.3
Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 7 
n= 102
```

Comment: I think this might help you along: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200646/how-to-estimate-location-and-scale-of-lognormal-distribution-using-survreg. The question might be more relevant for crossvalidated than for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Using simulations I would say that `Intercept` is the estimate of µ and `Scale` is the estimate of σ:

```
n <- 25000
y <- round(rlnorm(n), 2)
dat <- data.frame(left = y, right =y)
censored <- as.logical(sample.int(2, size=n, replace = TRUE) - 1L)
dat$left[censored] <- NA
dat$right[censored] <- 15

fit <- survreg(Surv(left, right, type = "interval2") ~ 1, data = dat, 
               dist = "lognormal")
summary(fit)
# (Intercept) -0.00712    0.00876 -0.81 0.42
# Log(scale)  -0.00568    0.00599 -0.95 0.34
# 
# Scale= 0.994
```

Another test:

```
n <- 100000
y <- rlnorm(n, meanlog = 2, sdlog = 0.5)
dat <- data.frame(left = y, right =y)
censored <- as.logical(sample.int(2, size=n, replace = TRUE) - 1L)
dat$left[censored] <- NA
dat$right[censored] <- 50

fit <- survreg(Surv(left, right, type = "interval2") ~ 1, data = dat, 
               dist = "lognormal")
summary(fit)
# (Intercept)  2.00004    0.00223  896 <2e-16
# Log(scale)  -0.69321    0.00314 -220 <2e-16
# 
# Scale= 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. So if I want to calculate the survivor function for lognormal, which is

(x)= 1−Φ(ln(x)/)

Does this mean that I should be able to do it by substituting σ with the value I got for Scale (1.56)?